# How to use CIFilter with CIPerspectiveCorrection on a capture session?

Tags: swift, core-image

I want to scan documents and fix any perspective issues with the phone like the notes App can do.
It is all fine until I want to use 
`CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")`, then I mess up the image and I am struggling to understand where I am going wrong.

I have tried to switch parameters and other filters, or rotate the image, but that didn't work for me.

Here is a small project I set up to test all this:
https://github.com/iViktor/scanner

Basically I am running a `VNDetectRectanglesRequest`on the `AVCaptureSession` and saving the rectangle I get in `private var targetRectangle = VNRectangleObservation()`

That one I am using to recalculate the points inside the image and to run the filter on the image.

```
extension DocumentScannerViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
        else { return }
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(data: imageData, options: [.applyOrientationProperty : true]) else { return }
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)

    let imageTopLeft: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * targetRectangle.bottomLeft.x, y: targetRectangle.bottomLeft.y * image.size.height)
    let imageTopRight: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * targetRectangle.bottomRight.x, y: targetRectangle.bottomRight.y * image.size.height)
    let imageBottomLeft: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * targetRectangle.topLeft.x, y: targetRectangle.topLeft.y * image.size.height)
    let imageBottomRight: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * targetRectangle.topRight.x, y: targetRectangle.topRight.y * image.size.height)

    let flattenedImage = image.flattenImage(topLeft: imageTopLeft, topRight: imageTopRight, bottomLeft: imageBottomLeft, bottomRight: imageBottomRight)
    let finalImage = UIImage(ciImage: flattenedImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

//performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto", sender: image)
//performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto", sender: UIImage(ciImage: flattenedImage))
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto", sender: finalImage)

}
}
```

This is the code that is not working, and I'm struggling with:

```
extension UIImage {

func flattenImage(topLeft: CGPoint, topRight: CGPoint, bottomLeft: CGPoint, bottomRight: CGPoint) -> CIImage {
    let docImage = self.ciImage!
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.size)
    let perspectiveCorrection = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")!
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: self.cartesianForPoint(point: topLeft, extent: rect)), forKey: "inputTopLeft")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: self.cartesianForPoint(point: topRight, extent: rect)), forKey: "inputTopRight")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: self.cartesianForPoint(point: bottomLeft, extent: rect)), forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: self.cartesianForPoint(point: bottomRight, extent: rect)), forKey: "inputBottomRight")
    perspectiveCorrection.setValue(docImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    return perspectiveCorrection.outputImage!
}

func cartesianForPoint(point:CGPoint,extent:CGRect) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: point.x,y: extent.height - point.y)
}
}
```

So in the end I want to scan a document, like a invoice and fix any user error like perspective issues automatically. Right now, the filter I add to the image results in a weird hand fan like effect.

Comment: I'll look at your project, but a quick question first: Is you Y coordinates correct? In `CoreImage`, the Y Axis is flipped. By that I mean the the "origin" point of 0,0 is in the **bottom** left instead of the upper left.

Comment: @dfd Yes, I use the last function above, cartesianForPoint(), to handle that. It that is not wrong.

Comment: I see that. I tried a few things, and what I'm seeing so far is (at least for my sample) the height - so yes, the Y values - you are feeding into `flattenImage` are wrong. I laid a small rectangular card on a carper and (1) `drawTargetRect` works fine, but even though the card width is greater than the height, the Y values coming into `flattenImage` has a heigh 4.5 times more than the width. The actual image values are 1080x1920 and the coordinates say the card is 435x1809. I'd check how you are computing things in `photoOutput`.

Comment: I've taken it as far as I can. f you check the coordinates between `targetRectLayer` and `targetRectangle` I think you'll see major discrepancies. In my test of a card that is more wide than tall, the "raw" values for the `TargetRectLayer.path` is spot on but the four coordinates of the `VNRectangleObservation` are not. I've dabbled with the Vision framework but know jut enough to make me dangerous. I guess the good news is that it appears  you are using `CIPerspectiveCorrection` correctly. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I will figure that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments I updated the code where I used the targetRectangle to instead use the points represented by the drawn path and changed where I used them for the image because CI uses a different coordinates system and the picture is mirrored.

I updated

```
    private func startScanner() {
         ... ... ...
               let request = VNDetectRectanglesRequest { req, error in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let observation = req.results?.first as? VNRectangleObservation {
                            let points = self.targetRectLayer.drawTargetRect(observation: observation, previewLayer: self.previewLayer, animated: false)
                            let size = self.scannerView.frame.size
                            self.trackedTopLeftPoint = CGPoint(x: points.topLeft.x / size.width, y: points.topLeft.y / size.height )
                            self.trackedTopRightPoint = CGPoint(x: points.topRight.x / size.width, y: points.topRight.y / size.height )
                            self.trackedBottomLeftPoint = CGPoint(x: points.bottomLeft.x / size.width, y: points.bottomLeft.y / size.height )
                            self.trackedBottomRightPoint = CGPoint(x: points.bottomRight.x / size.width, y: points.bottomRight.y / size.height )
                        } else {
                            _ = self.targetRectLayer.drawTargetRect(observation: nil, previewLayer: self.previewLayer, animated: false)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

and

```
extension DocumentScannerViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
        else { return }
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(data: imageData, options: [.applyOrientationProperty : true]) else { return }
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)

    // CoreImage is working with cartesian coordinates, basically y:0 is in the bottom left corner
    let imageTopLeft: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * trackedBottomLeftPoint.x, y: trackedBottomLeftPoint.y * image.size.height)
    let imageTopRight: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * trackedTopLeftPoint.x, y: trackedTopLeftPoint.y * image.size.height)
    let imageBottomLeft: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * trackedBottomRightPoint.x, y: trackedBottomRightPoint.y * image.size.height)
    let imageBottomRight: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * trackedTopRightPoint.x, y: trackedTopRightPoint.y * image.size.height)

    let flattenedImage = image.flattenImage(topLeft: imageTopLeft, topRight: imageTopRight, bottomLeft: imageBottomLeft, bottomRight: imageBottomRight)
    let newCGImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(flattenedImage, from: flattenedImage.extent)
    let doneCroppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: newCGImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto", sender: doneCroppedImage)
}
}
```

That fixed it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Good job on the answer.